# Return type of all sub directories from a given path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

hi i am doing my project i mvc4 using c#. I am trying to get all sub directories in a directory.and list it in my view

for that i am writing the following code

controller

```
public ActionResult Gallery()
    {
        string folderpath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Gallery/GalleryImages");
        List<string> currentimage = new Gallery().GetGalleryName(folderpath);
        //What will be the return type???/
        return View(currentimage);
    }
```

model

```
public List<string> GetGalleryName(string path)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        DirectoryInfo[] subdir = di.GetDirectories();
        List<String> files = new List<String>();
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in subdir)
        {
            var name = dir.Name;
            files.Add(name);
        }

        return files;
    }
```

Is my code is right? then what will be the return type in controller and model? please help me

Comment: did you get any error or something
?

Comment: try to run the code and check if it is right or not

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri: ya error in return subdir; and string[] currentimage = new Gallery().GetGalleryName(folderpath);

Comment: in model you are returning Array of DirectoryInfo and controller you are getting that array in String Array. so it might be Invalid Casting

Comment: then what will the return type?

Comment: try to return DirectoryInfo array to string Array and then return

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri: i am edited my code. is that correct. still error in  List<string> currentimage = new Gallery().GetGalleryName(folderpath);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change foreach loop in controller to

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in subdir)
        {
            files.Add(dir.Name);
        }
```

and change your controller from

```
public ActionResult Gallery()
    {
        string folderpath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Gallery/GalleryImages");
        string[] currentimage = new Gallery().GetGalleryName(folderpath);
        //What will be the return type???/
        return View(currentimage);
    }
```

to

```
public ActionResult Gallery()
    {
        string folderpath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Gallery/GalleryImages");
        List<String> currentimage = new Gallery().GetGalleryName(folderpath);
        //What will be the return type???/
        return View(currentimage);
    }
```

i hvn't tried it, but this should work. hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

change the foreach loop to below

```
 foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in subdir)
    {
                    files.Add(dir.FullName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller

```
public ActionResult Gallery()
{
  List<String> galleryList = new List<String>();
  string folderpath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Gallery/GalleryImages");
  string[] currentimage = new Gallery().GetGalleryName(folderpath);
  foreach (var folder in currentimage) {
    galleryList.Add(folder);
  }
return View(galleryList);
}
```